# Golang GET multipart form-data

Tags: html, go, get, multipartform-data

Let say I have a html form

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://localhost:8080/incarcat" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="file" multiple="multiple"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="delete">
    <input type="submit" value="Load" />
</form>
```

and the following go code

```
read_form, err := req.MultipartReader()
for {
    part, err_part := read_form.NextPart()
    if err_part == io.EOF {
        break
    }
    if part.FormName() == "file" {
        //do something with files
    } else if part.FormName() == "delete" {
        //curata_folder()
        log.Println("delete is: ", part.Header.Get("delete"))
    }
}
```

How do i get the value of "delete"?

```
part.Header.Get("delete"))
```

it's not working

Comment: for reading files from multipart data, use the request.FormFile which returns a reference to the file, the file header and error - http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.FormFile

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can probably content yourself by using the `request.ParseMultipartForm` method, then use the `request.FormValue` to get values as usual. Note that you also have the `request.MultipartForm` to get access to your files.

Example:

```
func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Here the parameter is the size of the form data that should
    // be loaded in memory, the remaining being put in temporary
    // files
    r.ParseMultipartForm(0)

    fmt.Println(r.FormValue("delete"))
}
```

Comment: This method reads the file contents into memory, where as mutlipartReader is used to stream the contents to disk or to another endpoint. I am still looking for an answer to OP's question.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. The questions was to access the value of the field, using specifically a `MultipartReader` don't seems to be the point here.

Comment: The question was about how to access the value of a field using MultipartReader, not ParseMultipartForm. This is necessary if we don't want to read the entire request into memory and/or temp files, which is what FormValue does when it calls ParseMultipartForm. The answer for how to do this with MultipartReader is to key off of part.FormName() when you are looping over the parts.

Comment: Well, it seems the OP was happy enough with my answer, so I guess you're wrong asserting his intention. Now, what you propose (*to key off of part.FormName*) doesn't makes any sense to me. If you really want to read a regular field using a `multipart.Part`, my guess is that you will have to use the `Part` as an `io.Reader`…

Comment: I am currently switching on part.FormName inside the loop for multipart.Reader in my own application and it works fine. While each multipart.Part does implement the io.Reader interface that does nothing to help you ascertain which form data param the part represents. The OP was probably just looking for a way to move on with their project and didn't really care about the memory and/or security implications of the solution. I was not asserting their intention at all, but addressing the literal question they asked, which happens to be what I wanted to know as well.

Comment: I thinked it would be obvious, given that the OP already switched on the `FormName`, that saying *use the Part as an io.Reader* was to get the value…

Comment: You are right... I think what they really wanted to know was just how to read the string value from a part/reader. I just demonstrated in a separate answer.

Answer (score 17):

The part implements the io.Reader interface. I am assuming what you are really asking is how to convert the part reader into a string, in the case that it is not a file. You can do so like this:

```
for {
   part, err_part := read_form.NextPart()
   if err_part == io.EOF {
      break
   }
   if part.FormName() == "delete" {
      buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
      buf.ReadFrom(part)
      log.Println("delete is: ", buf.String())
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The follow is an example of how to handle `multipart/form-data` and create a file from HTTP request using Golang.
Also, take a look in [here](https://medium.com/@effoeffi/how-to-test-a-go-rest-api-for-uploading-a-file-1c08275bb18) for how to **unit-test** it :)

```
func UploadFile(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
 if err := r.ParseMultipartForm(4); err != nil {
  w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
  return
 }

 // create a temporary directory
 dir, err := os.MkdirTemp("", "tmp")
 if err != nil {
  w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
  return
 }

 // create a temporary file
 f, err := os.CreateTemp(dir, "")
 if err != nil {
  _ = os.RemoveAll(dir)
  w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
  return
 }
 defer closeFile(f)
 defer os.RemoveAll(dir)

 code := doSomething(f)
 if code != http.StatusOK {
  w.WriteHeader(code)
  return
 }

 w.WriteHeader(http.StatusCreated)
 w.Write([]byte("Done :)"))
}
```